# How to reset array keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and would like to find the first matching element and return the value without the key being preserved.
I tried `array_intersect` but it preserves the key.

For example:

```
  $a = ['three', 'two', 'one'];
  $b = ['five', 'one'];

  $output = array_intersect($a, $b);
```

The resultant array returns `[2] => ['one']`

I just want this to be returned `[0] => ['one']`
Any workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
<?php
$a = ['three', 'two', 'one'];
$b = ['five', 'one'];

$output = array_values(array_intersect($a, $b));

print_r($output);
```

Example [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=820e5474c0d2b27ecdb6f561ae33fb44&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = ['three', 'two', 'one'];
$b = ['five', 'one'];
$output = array_values(array_intersect($a, $b));
```

> In your case, since `$a` and `$b` are first level arrays so
> [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is good enough but for higher level arrays, use
> [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$arr = array_intersect($a, $b);
$output = array_map('array_values', $arr);
```